# Java - regex for searching

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a regex string in Java.

Example

```
search - test
```

it should match the following TestCases

```
1. The test is done
2. me testing now
3. Test
4. tEST
5. the testing
6. test now
```

What i have right now (not working)

```
([a-z]+)*[t][e][s][t]([a-z]+)*
```

what could be the right regex code for this ??

Comment: The answer is **YY**, as in `Y not trY`... You can always play with regexes on a handful of sites, including [this one](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)...

Comment: Does is not work at all or only for some values? Java is case sensitive. I am not an expert on regex, but I am sure there are some on Stackoverflow that will solve this in a second :D

Comment: Why `[t][e][s][t]` instead of `test`? Also `([a-z]+)*` is simple way to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach can be that you call `String#matches` like this:

```
String search = "test";
String line = "The Testing";
boolean found = line.matches("(?i)^.*?" + Pattern.quote(search) + ".*$"); // true
```

Here `(?i)` is used for ignore case match and `Pattern.quote` is used for escaping possible regex special characters from `search` string.

Answer (score 1):

Try ((\w\s)*(test)(\s\w)*). Also use with the string you are searching into with toLower

```
String regex = "((\\w\\s)*(test)(\\s\\w)*)";
String text = "someTesTt";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text.toLowerCase());
if(matcher.find()) {
     // we have a match!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*test.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The regex to find a `test` word without differentiating the letters size would be

```
(t|T)(e|E)(s|S)(t|T)
```